# Never a Holomorphic Function

Tags: complex-analysis

So I had this question in my Quiz:
[image]

I found out the partial derivatives of v(x,y) as
$vy = 6xy$   and  $-vx = -3y^2$ .

**Both these derivatives are continuous and would have a suitable u(x,y) to satisfy the CR Equations.**

I don't get what is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just beacuse $v$ has continuous partial derivatives you cannot say that there is a harmonic conjugate $u$. If you had tried to find your $u$ you would have seen the difficulty.

Real and imaginary parts of a holomorphic function are harmonic. In this  case $v_{xx}+v_{yy}=6x$ so $v$ is not harmonic.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that there is suitable function $u$ such that $f$ is holomorphic. Then we have

$u_x=v_y=6xy$ hence $u(x,y)=3x^2y+c(y)$, where $c$ is a differentiable function which only depends on $y$.

Show that $u_y=-v_x$ does not hold.

Comment: This answer made me realize that one could also argue using differential forms. Indeed, if there is a function $u$ such that $$du=6xydx-3y^2dy, $$then arguing like here one arrives at a contradiction, essentially because the right-hand side is not a closed differential form.